# why the compiler forbids initialization of the array?

Tags: java, arrays, initialization

why the compiler forbids initialization of the array?

```
class Matrix {
    public int[] arr = null;
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.arr = {1, 2}; // compile error
        System.out.println(matrix.arr[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you declare an array you can use the syntax `public int[] arr = {1,2};`, but after declaration when you try to initialize it elsewhere (say in a method) you cannot use the shorthand you need to do it like `arr = new int[]{1,2};`.

This is because when you are declaring an array and you initialize it with some values `public int[] arr = {1,2};` the space for the array members (two in this case) is allocated and cannot be modified later unless you create a *new array object* and assign it to that field again. The **final** `length` property of the array object is set when you declare it using an array initializer.

But later on when you do `arr = new int[]{1,2};` you are actually creating a new array object and ***assigning*** to the already declared field.

**TL;DR**:

The array initializer syntax `{}` is only allowed during array declaration where the array constructor syntax `new type[]{}` is allowed after declaration in an assignment statement.

Answer (score 1):

When you create an array you need to do

```
matrix.arr = new int[]{1,2};
```